# Cylinder and sphere cuts

Tags: calculus

when we are asked to find the volume of the region cut from the solid cylinder $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, how can we find this region? Is it like the region bounded from above by the sphere and from below and the sides by the cylinder? And how do we know? A sketch will be helpful!

Comment: It’s the intersection of the two shapes

Comment: I know but I NEED A SKETCH PLEASE

Comment: It's basically a finite cylinder of radius $1$ with two spherical caps on the top and on the bottom. The height above the $xy$-plane of the cylindrical portion should be $\sqrt 3$ by Pythagoras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Does this very poor attempt at a sketch help in any way?

Comment: yes this is better!!!